# How to bucket field values in Einstein analytics

Tags: apex, einstein-analytics, saql

I have a dataset with a field as Order Country. It has field values as 'AUS', 'USA', 'GBR', 'IND', 'KEN', etc. 
Now, is there any way to bucket these values as

```
bucket 1: 'AUS', 'USA', 'GBR' - Total id count of these three countries
bucket 2: 'USA', 'GBR', 'IND', 'KEN' - Total id count of these Four countries
bucket 3: 'KEN', 'AUS', 'IND' - Total id count of these three countries
```

Please suggest

Answer (score 2):

Basically you have 2 options:

1. Bucket in a dataflow or recipe
2. Bucket in the dashboard. For that you have to write custom SAQL.
   In your query insert a line containing "case when" like the following

```
q = foreach q generate case when orderCountry in ["AUS", "USA", "GBR"]
                            then "Yes"
                            else "No"
                       end as Bucket1,
                       case when orderCountry in ["USA", "GBR", "IND", "KEN"]
                            then "Yes"
                            else "No"
                       end as Bucket2,
                       case when orderCountry in ["KEN", "AUS", "IND"]
                            then "Yes"
                            else "No"
                       end as Bucket3;
```

Then create subqueries to count

```
result1 = group q by Bucket1;
result1 = foreach result1 generate Bucket1, count() as countBucket1;

result2 = group q by Bucket2;
result2 = foreach result2 generate Bucket2, count() as countBucket2;

result3 = group q by Bucket3;
result3 = foreach result3 generate Bucket3, count() as countBucket3;
```

And finally union or cogroup the suqueries back together, depending on what you want to do with these numbers.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, however, I am not able to do a chart out of it now that I used the saql. Is that what the subqueries to count
=result part is for?

Comment: Please see the note about "commentary on...other answers" in [Why and how are some answers deleted?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers) & be aware that your "answer" will most likely be deleted. Please contribute to SFSE in other ways so that you gain reputation - you only need 15 rep to upvote a question & only 50 to comment under someone else's post. Or you could *Follow* the Q or A to be notified when it is updated, or possibly ask a [new question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/ask), and in it link to this Q or its other answer for reference.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/175751)